# Why would a serial device not be sending the correct start code?

Tags: esp32

I am unable to get any reading from a [PMS5003](https://www.aqmd.gov/docs/default-source/aq-spec/resources-page/plantower-pms5003-manual_v2-3.pdf) connected to an ESP32.

In trying to debug this problem, I have a very minimal setup. Only the PMS5003 is connected to the ESP32, and using the following the code.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#define PMS_DEBUG
#include <PMSerial.h>

SerialPM pms(PMSx003,Serial2)

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial2.begin(9600);
  pms.init();
}

void loop() {
  pms.read();
  Serial.println(pms.pm25);
  Serial.println(pms.status);
}
```

`pms25` always returns `0`. When the PMS5003 is properly connected to the ESP32, `status` always returns "Wrong message start".

Why would the device be sending the wrong start code, and what steps can I take to debug this?

I have tried connecting to different serial pins, including following the ESP32 software serial example provided by the [PMSerial](https://github.com/avaldebe/PMserial) library. In all cases, it simply looks as though the PMS5003 sensor is mot transmitting anything - indeed no fans are switching on and there is no sign of life at all from the device. However, I am very much a beginner, and don't know enough to tell whether this is a problem with the device, the library or something I have done.

Very grateful for suggestions how to debug this.

## Edit

example serial data

```
0x80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xC0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x6D, 0x0, 0xE0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x97, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xF8, 

0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xA, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0xB0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xF0, 0x0, 0x80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xBB, 0x1, 0x0, 0x5F, 0x0,
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the device ia working at 9600baud?

Comment: It would be helpful if you know what library you use. I found this one https://github.com/avaldebe/PMserial. The author provides some examples. Each of these  checking the state of pms with `if (pms)` after `read`. and only use the data if this is true. So perhaps the sensor is permanently read, but need some time to generate new data. So you have to check if the data is valid.

Comment: It seems the sensor signalizes that the data is valid with sending a 0x42 as a start byte. I've found an Arduino Project, which only uses the seirial connection, no extra driver and they only use the data if this 0x42 is received. Here is the link: https://how2electronics.com/interfacing-pms5003-air-quality-sensor-arduino/

Comment: thanks @PeterPaulKiefer! `pms` is never true because the `0x42` start byte is never received. I've added above an example of the data I'm receiving. I have double checked all my connections. As the start byte is not received, should I assume there is a problem with the sensor? Or are there other possible causes?

Comment: thanks @chrisl, the datasheet claims a default baud rate of 9600bps. added some links above

Comment: Can you show us how you have it wired to the ESP32?

Comment: The bytes you show have many sequences of consecutive bits. Please double check your connections and baudrate. Do you happen to have an oscilloscope? If so, probe the line and check the baudrate.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I was not notified, perhaps because of the ! behind the Name??   Perhaps (like mentioned in other comments) the baud rate is set to a non default. If you have access to an osci you could check that. Alternatively you could try out some common baud rates. Another good approach is to add a picture of your setup and the schematics. Then you got some reviews, that's also a form of trouble shooting. There are some rules mentioned in the documentation of the sensors. Did you pay attention to those. (e.g. Do not connect RESET if it is not used.)

Comment: thanks everyone for these suggestions. apologies for slow reply, things became very busy! I managed to borrow some spare components to test my project. Turns out there was a fault with the cable I was using to attach the PMS5003 sensor. Replaced the cable, everything works. Simple fix, but quite annoyed with myself for not checking this sooner!